# No mapping found for field

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, orm, doctrine, mapping

I have to Entities

```
class Patients 

    {
         /**
         * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ContactAddress", mappedBy="patients")
         */
        protected $contactaddress;
    }
```

And another

```
class ContactAddress
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Patients", inversedBy="contactaddress")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="patient_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
     protected $patient;
}
```

When I try execute this code

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$product = $em->getRepository('SurgeryPatientBundle:Patients')->find($id);
```

I get

```
No mapping found for field 'patients' on class 'Surgery\PatientBundle\Entity\ContactAddress'.
```

When i tried get to Contact repository I get result

Please Help ;D
Sorry for my English

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must refer to `patient` instead of patient*s* in ContactAddress entity.

```
class Patients 
{
     /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ContactAddress", mappedBy="patient")
     */
    protected $contactaddress;
}
```